# Zimbra connector

Tags: java, zimbra

I just discovered Zimbra and have a connector in Java to write. I have been looking on the web to find some documentation or experience from other people but could not find anything. Is there any good documentation of the API somewhere so I can get started and check what is possible to do with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API:

[Here](http://wiki.zimbra.com/index.php?title=ZCS_6.0%3aZimbra_REST_API_Reference)

There's a SOAP API, but it's..... very odd.... let me put that genorously. It is

[here](https://gist.github.com/428946)

Why is it "odd".It's WSDL-less, which is an interesting....choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer MJB. I will check what is REST, I am a beginner. I will digg into everything you gave me. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I can see that this API is for the 6.0 version of Zimbra, does it matters? Can I use it with Zimbra 7.0? Can the same API be used with the different versions of Zimbra? (Desktop, Open Source Edition, Application and Network Edition).

Comment: I also found this here: http://zimbra.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zimbra/trunk/ZimbraServer/src/java/com/zimbra/cs/account/ProvUtil.java?view=markup But cannot find any official doc about it. Is there any Java API?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to look in the docs folder of your Zimbra installation (usually /opt/www/docs if you are on linux) and have a look at soap.txt, soap-admin.txt and rest.txt depending on what you want to achieve.

The rest APIs are generally great for downloading a user's mailbox and other content such as contact and calendar entries as an archive, in case you want to back them up.

The admin apis are useful for managing the server and its users, checking the status, flushing the mail queue, etc.

If you want to implement client(user) functions, have a look at the source code for the Zimbra desktop client.

There is a post [here](http://blog.jeshurun.ca/technology/a-java-compliant-wsdl-for-zimbras-admin-soap-api) which provides a (partial) Java compliant WSDL file for the Admin SOAP api, and also a jar containing ready-to-use client proxies generated from them with CXF.